# LINQ to SQL check for Datetime is null or less then current date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I need to make LINQ query that will run SQL query

```
    Select * from Employee where Employee.StartDate is null OR 
(Employee.StartDate is not null AND Employee.StartDate > GetDate())
```

I tried following code

```
    Employee.Where(e => e.StartDate == null || 
(e.StartDate != null && e.StartDate > Datetime.Today);

    Employee.Where(e => e.StartDate.HasValue == false || 
(e.StartDate.HasValue != false && e.StartDate > Datetime.Today);

    Employee.Where(e => e.StartDate..Equals((DateTime?)null) || 
(e.StartDate.HasValue != false && e.StartDate > Datetime.Today);
```

but it does not generated the correct SQL to check both.

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL != Entity Framework. Which ORM do you use?

Comment: Can you show the SQL that the statements generate?

Comment: I am using EF 6.0

Comment: SQL statement is generated to check only that StartDate is greater then today and does not check for null

Comment: StartDate can't be null and also > GetDate(), you can just check > GetDate()

Comment: what DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. The query does not return tuples with StartDate as NULL. IT just returns tuples which have values and have greater than today

Comment: Are you sure the `StartDate ` field is nullable?

Comment: Is `StartDate` mapped as required, either by an attribute or by fluent mapping?

Comment: Yes. It is marked correctly but is there any attribute that would make big difference. It is DateTime? StartDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to tell what I mean in comments. It's almost certain that the property `StartDate` is mapped as required. This can either be done by data annotations...

```
[Required]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

...or by fluent mapping, for example in `OnModelCreating`...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .Property(e => e.StartDate).IsRequired();
```

Only under these circumstances will EF ignore a (not-)null check in a LINQ expression, because for all it knows the property can't be null.

Of course it doesn't make much sense to mark a nullable property as required, so you should either make it not nullable or not required.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thresholdDate = GetDate();
var employeesWithNewOrNoStartDate = dbContext.Employees
    .Where(employee => employee.StartDate == null
                    || employee.StartDate > thresholdDate);
```

In words:

from the sequence of all `Employees`, take only those `Employees` that have no `StartDate` at all, OR that have a fairly new `StartDate`

Comment: I ran SQL Profiler and SQL generated does not generates check for checking null

Comment: in that case it seems that StartDate is not nullable (at least in the model)

Comment: Ankit: maybe you should edit the question and add your `Employee` class

Answer (score 0):

```
var NewGroupEmployees = dbContext.Employees
.Where(employee => employee.StartDate == null
                || employee.StartDate > DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

This should return a list with the desired result.

Another option you could try is creating a **stored procedure** in SQL and call it from your application.

Comment: Sadly this does not compile to required SQL query and does not check for null date